# Java MyBatis How to find SUM of the Cases WHEN value is IN the list passing the list as a parameter to the mapper's method

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

In my Mapper Class I have a method with the example query:

```
 "<script>......"
    “GROUP BY acct, call, score HAVING sum(case when code in(\n" +
    "'PTP' \n" +
    "'RPCNPTP', \n" +
    "'LM3P', \n" +
    "'OM_SF',\n" +
    "'OM_SS',\n" +
    "'OM_UNV',\n" +
    "'OM_WR') then 1 else 0 end) <= intnsy ")        
"</script> "
List<Object> getData();
```

This query works just fine. But the actual list of Strings contains about 70 different strings and it's not a good idea to keep them in the query.
I need to pass that list as a parameter to the method and create a loop. Like this:

```
"<script>......"
    “GROUP BY acct, call, score HAVING sum(case when code in(\n" +
     "<foreach item='code' collection='myCodes' separator=',' open='(' close=')'>" +
        " (" +
        " #{code} " +
        " )" +
        " </foreach> " +
        ") then 1 else 0 end) <= intnsy " +
        "</script> ")
       List<Object> getData(@Param("myCodes") List<String> myCodes);
```

But i'm not able to make it work. The error is:

```
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Could not find value method on SQL annotation.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 933; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

Obviously I'm missing something simple here, but unfortunately have nobody else in my team to ask  Please point me to the right direction.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is special characters you have to treat in the list of strings.

For example, You have to escape the character `<` , because mybatis takes it as an unopened tag, `&lt` will work.

Comment: Yes, sir, that was exactly the problem with the query, solved other day.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
") then 1 else 0 end) <= intnsy "
```

changed '<' to '<'

```
") then 1 else 0 end) &lt;= intnsy "
```

now the query works as intended